# Improve Performance Window function Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying run the hive query below with the windowing function and it's taking forever.  I'm hoping someone has some tips on what I could do to speed it up.  table1 below has close to 1 billion records and table2 only has a few thousand.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
SELECT up.uid,up.ban,up.ban_pref,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY up.uid ORDER BY up.ban_pref DESC, bnp.tot_pod DESC) AS rank
FROM table1 AS up
INNER JOIN table2 AS bnp ON up.ban=bnp.ban
```

Comment: look at the execution plan for the query and go from there..one suggestion would be to declare the largest table last.. (table1 in this case)

Comment: please add the execution plan to your question. You should be able to perform a mapjoin considering the side of your second table. can you talk about the distribution of uid after the join? maybe there are a few groups with too many records (for example an invalid uid (just guessing)

Answer (score 0):

May be this would have already been resolved. But, my thoughts.
1. First try to complete the join using map side join as second table is small. This can be done using Hive.auto.convert.join = true.
2. In the next step try to have the window function executed.